# putting <input type="button"> and their <label> in line

Tags: input, label

Hi everyone I am making the freeCodeCamp to learn coding, and I'm doing the certification project survey form, and I'm supposed to do a form with button inputs, the last 3 hours I was trying to put the input button and the label in-line I tried so many things got so many weird different shapes but i didn't get it to be in-line, until I randomly made it without knowing it. I don't understand how I made it work, but it works I have seen other people doing the same thing but with a way different code, so I wanted to ask if I did it right or is my code week wrong or bad, or did I do good? And the second question is how does the code that I did work, why is it working.

Choose your method of receiving your order
  Delivery
      C&C
      C&C (with authorization)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.